# Using a analog multiplexer to use 9 serial input sensors?

Tags: serial

I have 9 sensors, they will send a datastring to my Arduino through Tx/Rx (every 3½ seconds, pre-programmed). The only problem is that there's only one Tx/Rx port on an Arduino Uno. Is it possible to use an analog multiplexer to "make" more Serial ports? Because the sensors send something every 3½ seconds, there's no need to be fast.

EDIT: It's a Temperature and Relative Humidity Sensor

Comment: what sensor? can you add a link?

Comment: Not that it matters particularly, but every 3-5 seconds or 3.5 seconds?

Comment: exact model of the sensor please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not unless you can change your communication protocol to be a "call-and-response" protocol.

Basically, the problem is this: *when* do you switch to *which* serial device? Unless all the devices have their timing synchronised there is no way of knowing - so how do you control your analogue multiplexer in that situation...?  You can't.

You would need to have some method of the master switching the multiplexer to a specific peripheral, then send a message to that peripheral saying "Send me your data now".

You would be better off investigating other boards with more UART ports, such as the Mega2560, and having multiple boards.

The Mega2560 has 4 UART ports. You can have 4 sensors per board (5, if you want to use SoftwareSerial or, better, AltSoftSerial), so you could get away with two boards.

One board acts as normal, communicating on the UART ports to 4 sensors, and also acts as an I2C or SPI master (the choice is yours). The second board communicates to 4 more sensors on UARTs and one further on using AltSoftSerial etc. It also acts as an I2C or SPI slave device.

The "slave" board just runs autonomously gathering data from the sensors it is directly connected to and storing those values.  The "master" then periodically asks the "slave" board for the latest data.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer and my apologies for the late answer.
I just tried a multiplexer, because some people said that I would work. I can receive info from all the 9 sensors. The sensor sends a datastring and I filter the temperature and relative humidity and then I switch to the next sensor. It works quite well, the only problem is that you can't request the datastring, so you should wait till the datatstring is sent